# How to choose optimal number of clusters using scikit-learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, cross-validation

I would like to find the optimal number of clusters for a clustering algorithm using silouette scoring and a pre-computed distance matrix.  In the example below I am using `AgglomerativeClustering` (but I might want to use a different clustering algorithm in the future).

```
from sklearn import cluster, metrics, model_selection


# define some clustering model
agglomerative_clustering = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(affinity="precomputed")

def _silhouette_scoring(clustering_model, distances):
    return metrics.silhouette_score(distances, clustering_model.labels_, metric="precomputed")

# define distributions over parameters to optimize
n, _ = distances.shape
param_distributions = {'n_clusters': stats.randint(low=1, high=n),
                       'linkage': ["complete", "average"]}

prng = np.random.RandomState(42)
parameter_sampler = model_selection.ParameterSampler(param_distributions, n_iter=100, random_state=prng)

optimal_params = None
optimal_params_score = -np.inf

for i, sampled_params in enumerate(list(parameter_sampler)):
    agglomerative_clustering = cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(affinity="precomputed", **sampled_params)
    agglomerative_clustering.fit(distances)
    sampled_params_score = _silhouette_scoring(agglomerative_clustering, distances)

    if sampled_params_score > optimal_params_score:
        optimal_params, optimal_params_score = sampled_params, sampled_params_score
```

Running the above code works but I feel like choosing the optimal number of clusters is a pretty common task and that there should be some way to do this within `sklearn.model_selection` using `RandomizedSearchCV` or `GridSearchCV` or similar.  How can this be done?

Comment: Not implemented yet. There are a couple open issues and a PR in Github for that. See [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6154), and [this PR](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/6160).